# Insert value in table relationship Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I want to insert some value in db, but I get an error, and I am not sure why.

> Trying to get property 'lkp_relationship_correlation' of non-object**

```
 $person = new Person();

    foreach ($request->relationship_values as $item) {
        $relationship = new Relationship();
        $relationship->fill([
            'lkp_relationship_correlation_id' => $item->lkp_relationship_correlation,
            'relative_fullname' => $item->relatives_surname,
            'relative_surname' => $item->relatives_full_name,
            'relative_id' => 3,
        ]);

        $relationship->person()->associate($person)->save();
    };

public function person()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Person::class, 'person_id');
}

public function relationship()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Relationship::class);
}

dd($item);
```

> array:3 [   "lkp_relationship_correlation" => 11   "relatives_surname"
>   => "Simona"   "relatives_full_name" => "Simona Arabu" ]

Comment: Well, it means your `$item` is not an object, is it perhaps an array? Try `var_dump($item);` to see

Comment: It's array, I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `$item` is an array, you can't do this:

```php
$item->lkp_relationship_correlation
```

You can access the `lkp_relationship_correlation` value like:

```
$item['lkp_relationship_correlation']
```